# What are all the restrictions by Apple for iPhone development

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone development and I would like to know that what are all the restrictions by Apple for iPhone developers. What shouldn't be used by the developers in order to get the app approved by Apple? I searched a lot and I found the Apple recommendations and guidelines but I didn't find the restrictions of Apple for iPhone development.

Thanks for your answers.
[Appstore review guidelines.](http://way2ios.com/development/ios-development-2/app-store-review-guidelines/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tips for a successful AppStore submission?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551/tips-for-a-successful-appstore-submission)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at these links:

1 ) http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4213

2) http://techcrunch.com/2008/03/07/iphone-sdk-some-of-the-details-arent-great/

3) http://blog.mcohen.me/2008/03/07/iphone-sdk-restrictions/

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to access files outside of your App's sandbox.  Don't load shared libraries.  Don't link to Apple's private frameworks.

Don't use a jailbreak - or if you do, sell your App in one of the stores for jailbreak Apps, but not Apple's App Store.  Jailbreak Apps are perfectly legal, provided you didn't sign the iPhone Developer Agreement that you have to sign to get an iOS developer program membership.

You can use a cross-platform application framework, but you cannot run a code interpreter, and you cannot download code from the Internet.  Why Apple considers that a problem is completely beyond my comprehension, because any App can use the iOS-provided UIWebView, which includes a Javascript interpreter, so in principle your native App could be a front-end for a purely interpreted App written entirely in Javascript.

Apple is down with Javascript, just don't try using Java, Flash, Perl or Python.

Don't reverse engineer the iOS or your devices.

If you don't sign the iOS developer program agreement, you can do just about anything you damn well please, but if you violate any of the above, Apple won't accept your App in the App Store.  But if you do sign the agreement, violating any of these terms might result in a B-52 bomber dropping Thousand Pound Lawyer Bombs on your office.

Comment: Thanks for the info. i need to know more about coding restrictions(i.e we can't add images to navigation-bar etc.) will be more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you also read this:
[App store review guidelines for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)